# CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME blank?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile for Linux (with Generator *Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja*) but when I am checking for `${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}` in `CMakeLists.txt`, all I get is blank.

In which scenarios is using this variable valid?

Using cmake 3.02 from Debian Testing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to place [CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) after [project](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) command:

```
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
project(Foo)
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
```

Result:

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
...
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue, and work it out.

All i want to do is cross compile on Linux server with `aarch64-himix100-linux`, and compile with the default toolchain on Darwin system.

I use [CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME.html#variable:CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME) instead of [CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html).

The value of `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME` is equal to the output of `uname -s`.

For example,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

if (NOT ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Toolchain-aarch64-himix100-linux.cmake")
endif ()

project(phoenix)
```

Comment: This arguably is a better answer, as any compiler-related commands have to occur _before_ the project statement.